# Multiple different components on a page, each using the same loader component - how to make them unique?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a loader component for Angular (5).
The loader component sits within different child components, which themselves are within an overall parent component.

So, for example, the parent component has two components in the view:

```
<app-abc></app-abc>
<app-xyz></app-xyz>
```

Each of those components call a different endpoint, while that endpoint is being called, I want to show a loading animation, but it needs to be unique to the component that is calling it. I could just repeat code in each component that triggers a loader, but I'd rather create a loading component that can be shared across the entire application.

This loading component has a boolean showLoading variable which is set by calling a setShowLoading method in the loader component.

```
this.loadingService.setShowLoading(true);
```

The loader component view has an *ngIf to either display or not display the loading animation, based on the value of a boolean variable type.

Everything works great with just a single loader component, but as soon as two components each have that loader component within them on a page, they are both invoked.

I've been thinking about passing in an ID parameter, but I'm not convinced this will solve the issue or be performant.

I thought because the loader component is within two different components, it's scope would be encapsulated. Turns out it isn't.

Is there a simple method to ensure that this loader component is unique within it's parent components view?

Comment: why don't you implement an HTTP interceptor, with a universal loader in the root component.

Comment: Or you can use a "count" variable? (your parent component like < app-loader [count]=2><app-abc><app-xyz>), and instead send a setShowLoading(true) use a lessCount()

Comment: Your service is probably a singleton, but it shouldn't be. Each component using a loader should have its own LoaderService, declared in the component providers.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure why you need a service. Just pass the loading flag as an input to the loader component: `<app-loader [loading]="isLoading"></app-loader>`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was super simple.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'component-abc',
   templateUrl: './component-abc.component.html',
   providers: [ LoadingComponent ]
})
```

The component using the Loading service needs to declare it as a provider in order to make that service a singleton for just that component.

From :

https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#scenario-service-isolation